# s3_direct_upload rails gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to hook up my Rails app to upload files to an amazon s3 server, but the ruby gem s3_direct_upload isn't working. Here's the code I've added.

star.js.coffee under assets/javascript

```
#= require s3_direct_upload

jQuery ->
  $("#myS3Uploader").S3Uploader
    path: 'path/to/my/files/on/s3'
    additional_data: {key: 'value'}
    remove_completed_progress_bar: false
    before_add: myCallBackFunction # must return true or false if set
    progress_bar_target: $('.js-progress-bars')
    click_submit_target: $('.submit-target')
```

under uploads.html.erb

```
    <%= s3_uploader_form callback_url: 'model_url', callback_param: "model[image_url]", id: "s3-uploader" do %>
        <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: true %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: "is not working" - how? the code is not running? you get an exception (please add it to the post)? everything looks fine, but the file does not appear in s3?

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but isn't it easier to just handle the uploads with Paperclip and aws-sdk ?

Comment: To Uri, that's correct. The JQuery progress bar doesn't show up, and the files do not show up on the EC2 services. And The Mini John, I would just use paperclip, but I need one user to be able to upload multiple files. Isn't the way Paperclip is usually implemented is one user has one file (usually an image or avatar)?